# How to connect local Windows applications like Conda and MySQL from Ubuntu on WSL2?

Tags: kubuntu, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, anaconda

I have recently installed WSL2 (Ubuntu) in Windows 11 to learn about its commands and working with. Everything is working fine, but I am unable to access my Windows applications from within Ubuntu.

For example, in Windows, I have installed Anaconda and MySQL which I am able to access from Git Bash, CMD, or PowerShell but not from within Ubuntu in WSL2.

I use WSL for most of the time for my work, but I am unable to work with local Windows applications.

I tried to export the path of my Anaconda and MySQL to zsh, but it's still not working:

```bash
export PATH="/mnt/c/Users/verma/anaconda3/Library/bin:$PATH"
```

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  A quick clarification -- You have this tagged as both [tag:kubuntu] and [tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux].  I think the Kubuntu tag is probably incorrect in this case, since Kubuntu isn't normally a distribution that you would run under WSL.  I'm assuming you are using Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store under WSL, correct?  If that's the case, just delete the Kubuntu tag so that those that watch for that tag aren't drawn to this question unnecessarily - Thanks!

Comment: Second question - In your question title, you say "connect", but then your question body makes me think you mean "run".  Are you trying to *connect* a network application in Ubuntu to a network application in Windows?  Or are you trying to *run* a Windows application from Ubuntu?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I am trying to open conda environment or connect my local mysql db  and similar thing

Comment: @DarkstarDream those are not similar things, tbh

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your comment (and question body) correctly, it sounds like you may really be asking two different questions:

- From Ubuntu/WSL2, how to *run* an application like Anaconda that is installed in Windows.
- From Ubuntu/WSL2, how to use an Ubuntu application (like the MySQL client) to *connect* to a network application (like the MySQL server) that is running in Windows.

###### Running Windows applications from Ubuntu in WSL

This part is both easy but comes with warnings.

In a default WSL configuration, there are two parts to running a Windows application:

- Make sure it is on the path OR provide a fully-qualified path
- Use the *complete* name, including the `.exe` extension.  Linux does not have an automatic kernel-level assumption of extensions like Windows.

So, for instance, to run Notepad:

```
notepad.exe
```

Since it is on the default Windows path (which WSL makes available to Ubuntu automatically).

To run, say, Microsoft Word:

```
/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ Office/root/Office16/WINWORD.EXE
```

Since Office is not on the default Windows path, you need to specify the full command-line.

Note that some applications may require certain configuration through a PowerShell script.  I'm not certain, but I think Anaconda may fall into this category.  In that case, you'll need to first execute PowerShell and then have *it* launch the application.  Something like:

```
powershell -c conda
```

However (*[here be dragons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_be_dragons)*), note that even if you do get it running, Windows Python from within Ubuntu in WSL is a bad idea in general.  The Windows version of Python isn't going to be able to understand, for instance, Linux paths or processes, which WSL/Ubuntu will pass to it by default.

Virtual environments won't work for the same reason, since the paths that Windows Python tries to set won't be valid in Linux/Ubuntu/WSL.

In addition, any native-code modules will be running in the *Windows* environment, not in the Ubuntu environment, with the same path/process limitations.  Things will quickly get confusing, both for you and for the code/interpreter.

Inside Ubuntu/WSL, use the Linux version of Python and, if needed, Anaconda.  In Windows, use the Windows version.

###### Connecting to Windows network applications/servers from Ubuntu in WSL2

WSL2 is actually running on a separate, virtualized, NAT'd network from your Windows host.  As such, you need to determine the proper IP address to use for the Windows host in order to connect to it from the WSL2 network.

Assuming a default WSL/Ubuntu installation on a supported Windows release, mDNS is usually the best option.

The mDNS name of your Windows host that you can use from within Ubuntu will look like:

```
MyComputerName.local
```

As long as you haven't changed the DNS resolver from the WSL default, that will be the same as what you see when you run `hostname` in Ubuntu.

You can determine this programmatically by:

- Obtaining the hostname in your programming language / environment
- Appending `.local`

For instance, in Bash, to connect to a Windows MySQL server:

1. Install the MySQL client in Ubuntu:

   ```
   sudo apt install mysql-client
   ```
2. Connect to Windows MySQL server via `"$(hostname).local"`:

   ```
   mysql --hostname=$(hostname).local --user=me -p mydb
   ```

Comment: I am getting `Access denied for user 'root'@'172.21.128.5' (using password: YES)` when i try `mysql -h Aman.local -u root -p`. I didn't used your 2nd code cuz it was giving `[ERROR] unknown variable 'hostname=.local'`

Comment: @DarkstarDream That's likely because the `root` user in MySQL only exists for `'root'@'localhost'`.  And since WSL2 is on a remote network (from Windows), you'll need to create a root user that can log in from remote hosts. Creating `'root'@'%'` and setting a password on that account should work.  See [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11223235/11810933) for details.

Comment: Also, the `=` error is probably just a quoting issue - Sorry I wasn't able to try it out to be sure.